# Loading Django Database Using Script

Tags: django, model

I was looking to fill my Django model fields with data using a Python script.  I know that if you had a Publisher model you could go into `python manage.py shell` and do:

```
>>> from books.models import Publisher
>>> p1 = Publisher(name='Apress', address='2855 Telegraph Avenue',
...     city='Berkeley', state_province='CA', country='U.S.A.',
...     website='http://www.apress.com/')
>>> p1.save()
```

How could I run similar code in a Python script without going into the manage.py shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [point to the settings](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/) yourself.